# How to identify users who have visited at least 3 blog posts

Tags: google-analytics

Another Google Analytics segmentation question:  I want to create a segment of individuals who have read (visited the page at least) 3 or more blog posts (/blog) over time.
Then I can compare eventual conversion rates to people who never read the blog.  In other words, can I create a segment that can help me answer the question if it pays off to write blogs and promote them!
Thanks.
Would be curious to know a segment both within a session (read 3 blogs in a session) vs by user (read 3 blogs across any sessions)

Answer (score 1):

Sequence segments to your rescue. They help to get quite granular detail.
**Filter** > Include > Sessions **Sequence start** > Any user interaction 
Segment contains 3 steps. 
Each step configured as Page contains /blog (or pattern/regex applicable to your blog urls)
*followed by*

Some great articles online if you do a google search for *analytics sequence segments*. They offer some useful suggestions and uses for them.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if you are using Google Tag Manager (If not that is my super high recommendation to do because it would make your life easier not only for MarTech but as well for other stuff). Therefore your best friends in this case are cookies or local storage. There is very simple to follow instruction about how to create end edit cookies, which later can be used as a variable to trigger some events which will eventually help you create a group of users that read 2,3,4,5 etc blog posts. here is the link.

https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/cookies-with-google-tag-manager/